# Android - Google maps V2 - Removing a groundoverlay

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, gmsgroundoverlay

My app uses google maps v2, I add a groundoverlay to my map. Does anyone know how I can remove this overlay?
Thanks

.remove() doesn't seem to available

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is the method remove():
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html#remove()

You just have to keep a reference to the ground overlay when you create it:

```
 GroundOverlay groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
     .image(image)
     .positionFromBounds(bounds)
     .transparency(0.5));
```

then remove:

```
groundOverlay.remove();
```

Comment: well that's what I thought too but .remove() doesn't seem to be there :/

Comment: Read the answer carefully. In your screenshot, you are trying to call `remove()` on a `GroundOverlayOptions` object. You need to call `remove()` on the `GroundOverlay` object itself, which is returned when you called the `addGroundOverlay()` method.

Comment: ahhh I see! Thank you!